Return values to column A if they are missing from Column B
I have two tables in Google Sheets

Table A is always going to be smaller or equal size to Table B and is static
Table B is updated daily from BigQuery so new values are added daily

Table A
A
B
C
Table B (Monday refresh)
A
B
C
E
F
Table B ( Tuesday refresh)
A
B
C
E
F
D
I want a formula which is adding to Table A only the missing values from Table B. So it checks the values of the cells previously in A and adds what is missing only.
So on Monday Table A will only add E - F and and on Tuesday it will only add D since they are the new cells from previous refresh without changing the data in the previous rows
I tried =ISNA(MATCH(A2:A, B2:B, 0)) and =FILTER(A2:A,ISNA(MATCH(A2:A,B2:B,0))) but it gives me error because I want the new value to be added in A4.

The filter() formula you quote is the usual way to do this, but you cannot use formulas to overwrite existing data, so the formula should be in another column — see Spreadsheet Value Rule. The Tuesday refresh includes duplicate values and it is unclear how they should be handled. Please [edit] the question and add the desired results you would like to see.

and is static, I want the new value to be added in A4 A formula isn't going to create a static value. You need a script  to make the updates on Table A.

You want to find values on ListB that aren't on ListA, and add those values to ListA.
Consider this answer:

List A is retrieved and flattened
List B is retrieved as a 2D array
the values on List B are compared to List A, and any non-matching values are added to a temporary array.
the array is added to List A.

The function trigger is a matter for the OP. A time-driven trigger is probably Ok.

function updateTableA() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheetA = ss.getSheetByName("Table A")
  var sheetB = ss.getSheetByName("Table B")

  // get table A data as a 1D array
  var aVals = sheetA.getRange("A2:A").getValues();
  var aLast = aVals.filter(String).length;
  var tableARange = sheetA.getRange(2,1,aLast,1)
  Logger.log("DEBUG: Table A range = "+tableARange.getA1Notation())
  var tableAData = tableARange.getValues().flat()
  Logger.log(tableAData) // DEBUG

  // get table B data
  //const col_g_flat = col_g.flat();//// ['a','b','c',..]
//const not_match = new_opt.filter(x => !col_g_flat.includes(x/*access the string inside*/[0]));

  // get table B data
  var bVals = sheetB.getRange("A2:A").getValues();
  var bLast = bVals.filter(String).length;
  var tableBRange = sheetB.getRange(2,1,bLast,1)
  Logger.log("DEBUG: Table B range = "+tableBRange.getA1Notation())
  var tableBData = tableBRange.getValues()
  Logger.log(tableBData)

  // find the non-matching values on table B
  var not_match =tableBData.filter(x => !tableAData.includes(x/*access the string inside*/[0]));
  Logger.log(not_match) // DEBUG

  if (not_match.length > 0){
    Logger.log("DEBUG: range to set = "+sheetA.getRange(aLast+2,1,not_match.length,1).getA1Notation())
    sheetA.getRange(aLast+2,1,not_match.length,1).setValues(not_match)
  }
  else{
    Logger.log("DEBUG: no records to update")
  }
}

h/t @TheMaster for Create a list with values not contained in a Google Sheets column via Google Apps Script

